# how to generate "for loop" in YAML file

Tags: yaml

suppose we have the following YAML

```
a:
  - s1: p
  - s2: p
  - s3: p
  - s4: p
```

is there a syntax using for loop to generate this YAML file

like:

```
enum: [s1,s2,s3,s4]
a:
for t in enum:
  -t:p
```

writing a script is a way to do this. Is this feasible?

Comment: There is nothing in YAML that can do that, but there is a multitude of programs that use some templating system (e.g. `jinja2`) that expands to YAML. You should therefor look into a templating system for the programming language you are using.

Comment: BTW, you get better looking blocks of code/YAML if you select the block and press Ctrl+K to indent the whole block instead of putting backquotes around the block (those are better for inline pieces of code)

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to shorten a YAML file the way you are planning to do.

A solution would be a script that interprets the file and shortens it the way you like, which would only be usable for readability.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are trying something like yaml template in azure devops :
Try something like:

```
${{each img in parameters.images}}:
      ${{img.key}}:
```